# sharepoint 2013 on-premise copy document between site collections using rest api

Tags: site-collection, sharepoint-rest-api, document

Can I copy documents between site collection using rest api?
I know its possible within the same library and also between sub-site. I need to send copies a number of documents from one library to another libraryt in a diffrent site collection, same domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, i'd suggest to you the below article for details on how to achieve this:

[Moving a File to Another Site Collection, Using REST, High Trust App Only Permissions, AND in a Console Program - SharePoint 2013 On Premises](http://ramblingsofamadcomputerguy.blogspot.com/2015/09/moving-file-to-another-site-collection.html)